# Why am I getting "Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'." error in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a sporcle-esque quiz game for a school project regarding the top scorers in NBA History so the way I'm doing is I have an array of all the top 25 scorers (in order) and I have a seperate array of their respective point totals. So I'm trying to build out a table using javascript and looping through the for loop.

This is my code for that:

````
{
    var row = document.createElement("tr")
    mytable.appendChild(row)
    var rank = document.createElement("td")
    rank.innerHTML = i+1+""

    row.id = answers[i];
    var name = document.createElement("td")
    name.innerHTML = answers[i]
    var points = document.createElement("td")
    points.innerHTML = points[i]

    row.appendChild(rank)
    row.appendChild(name)
    row.appendChild(points)
} ```

When I run this I get this error "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'." and the error comes at the second last line when I say "row.appendChild(name)"

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error.
````

Comment: probable because of the variable named `name` ... seriously, call it something else

Comment: ^^ or better yet, don't create global variables (put your code in a module on modern browsers, or in a wrapper function).

Comment: why is using "name" bad? I'm new to web dev